# Reporting of expired links in answers to locked posts

Tags: support, link-only-answers, broken-link, locked

Since it's not editable nor reportable; how do I report an [expired link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba)?

[image: expired locked link]

Comment: You mean posts with a historical lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reporting it here on Meta is fine, since that seems to be your only option.  We don't lock a lot of posts permanently, and when we do we normally clean up any link-only answers beforehand. This should be a rare thing.  Thanks for pointing it out.